# java.lang.NullPointerException: No FileItemFactory has been set

Tags: java, servlets

In attempting to implement fileUpload using the streaming API I get an error described below:
As I gather from [the Streaming API](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html) web page that the "traditional FileItemFactory is completely ignored," I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. So I've defined a basic method as follows:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param
 * @return
 */
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    // Check that we have a file upload request
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    if (isMultipart) {

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();                 // Create a new file upload handler

            // Parse the request
            try {
Line 39 -->         List items = upload.parseRequest(request);                      // FileItem
            Iterator iter = items.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = (FileItemStream) iter.next();

                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    this.processFITSFile(item);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

But that leads to the error below:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet FitsFileProcessorServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: No FileItemFactory has been set.
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:353)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at controller.FITSFileProcessor.doPost(FITSFileProcessor.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you mark the line in your code that causes the error? (Line 39, I guess)

Comment: The line 39 should be `List items = upload.parseRequest(request);`

Comment: yes that's right. edited the code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`new ServletFileUpload()` creates an uninitialized instance. Its documentation says:

> Constructs an uninitialised instance
>   of this class. A factory must be
>   configured, using
>   setFileItemFactory(), before
>   attempting to parse requests.

So you either need to use `setFileItemFactory()` or use the other constructor, which takes the factory as an argument. Like this:

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
```

Fore more info, see [the documentation](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html). The example is also from there.

Or, you can use the [streaming API](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html), but then you need to get the iterator differently:

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItemStream item = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

Comment: but then doing so yields:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream
 controller.FITSFileProcessor.doPost(FITSFileProcessor.java:46)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: You need to do `upload.getItemIterator(request)` if you want to use the streaming API, see http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html